# How to run curl --retry command in GitLab-ci.yml

Tags: ssl, curl, gitlab-ci

i am trying to run a curl --retry command in GitLab-ci pipeline and it fails in the pipeline but when i try to run it somewhere else it's working fine.

I am trying to check if my url is up or not and this will run till my url is up and after that rest of my script run to configure my application

> curl -Is -k --retry 50 --retry-delay 0 --retry-connrefused https://{URL} -vvv

- Trying 127.0.1.1:8443...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to {url} (127.0.1.1) port 8443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
  } [5 bytes data]
- TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  } [512 bytes data]
- OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to {url}
- Closing connection 0
  Cleaning up file based variables
  ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

I think what is happening here that when we run curl --retry for every retry it closes the connection and restart it and that's where my pipeline breaks and i am not able to figure out how to handle this.
Is there any workaround to do this in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple bash script and check for curl return value:

```
while true; do if curl --location 'http://localhost:8080'; then break; else sleep 1; fi; done
```